# How to cleanup docker?

Tags: unix, docker, containers, ubuntu-16.04

We are using docker for continuous builds. I have removed the unwanted images and containers. Just have 4 images of 5GB max. But looks like something else is eating up all the disk space. Any tips how to cleanup and improve space?

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             48G     0   48G   0% /dev
tmpfs           9.5G   26M  9.5G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       456G  428G  5.2G  99% /
tmpfs            48G  7.4M   48G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            48G     0   48G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/lxcfs/controllers
tmpfs           9.5G     0  9.5G   0% /run/user/1000
none            456G  428G  5.2G  99% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4b96935f7fb6b517031df23849292a06eab92013d0610d922588688132013a5e
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/c3b48e0215e05e13f79466de64cb0a2b4646cef30e020e651c59cb1950f0d70d/shm
none            456G  428G  5.2G  99% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4388442c65c13654a7d1cd51894aa5c06137166628a0a52d6854abc230417140
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/027ce91cd66eca1ed134decdb8c13e6676fd34b1f6affe406513220037e63936/shm
none            456G  428G  5.2G  99% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/13595cb64024d0d8f3cf7c09f90e37baccee08ea9b9b624c41d971a195d614e0
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/3212761e701699313a127d50a423677c1d0ddaf9099ae37e23b25b8caaa72b37/shm
none            456G  428G  5.2G  99% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/149839edbef826cdf289e66988c206dd6afebdb4257cc22e91551f65ea034f77
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/9c084651b9ecf035257a34b9dd4415689e4c685e660e3013ad9673955834be
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The common mistake is to forget to delete the volumes.

For CI and CD it's a good practice to use `docker rm -v` when removing a container, with the -v you are sure that the auto-created volumes are deleted.

To be sure, type `docker volume ls` if you have some values here that means that some of your containers created some volumes.

You can get rid of them all at once with `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)` (it will not remove any currently used volumes and will display an error message instead, but use with caution)

Comment: I ran : docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)   still 22gb not free how to clear it : none            148G  121G   22G  85% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/def4f3913e9b56b064c9e17b01599943982c454a72fc3ba3d674effc619a22a1
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7b690ecd69c8f0f3113306ecbdc54f330508f03806c35b65311b866ebf5d29b7/mounts/shm

Answer (score 9):

After Docker version 1.13, there are [new prune commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) to cleanup docker environment.

use `docker system df` to get statistics about containers, images and their disk usages with reclaimable space.

use `docker system prune` to get rid of stopped containers, dangling volumes and dangling images.

To remove only stopped containers you can use `docker container prune` and `docker image prune` to remove all dangling images.

Comment: I ran "docker container prune" & "docker image prune" still 22gb not freed  how to clear it : none 148G 121G 22G 85% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/def4f3913e9b56b064c9e17b01599943982c454a72fc3ba3d674effc619a22a1 shm 64M 0 64M 0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7b690ecd69c8f0f3113306ecbdc54f330508f03806c35b65311b866ebf5d29b7/mounts/shm

Answer (score 4):

You can clean up docker artifacts by using the following command (depending on what you need to clean up):

```
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker network prune
docker volume prune
```

These commands support '-a' option that will delete all of the artifacts if specified (for example `docker container prune -a` will remove all the containers)

In case you need to clean up everything you may want to use:

```
docker system prune -a
```

This is like all of the commands mentioned above combined.